# Gitlab ci omnibus access rights

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

i have gitlab  omnibus, 8.0.4 version, installed on private server, we need to remove access right from reporter to read/pull/download code,

so we dont want reporter to viewer the source code

I think it can be done through editing some file on the server, right?

how can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporter always has read access to files, issues and merge requests. This cannot be altered (and we do not recommend modifying source files since it makes upgrades more difficult).

My suggestion is to create a separate project with only the issue tracker enabled and add the user as a reporter there. Keep the project with source code private.

#### Danger section ;)

If you really want to modify the code, look in `app/models/ability.rb`. In the `project_report_rules` method remove the rights you do not wish 'reporter' to have.

Comment: we are ready to take the risk of editing source code and handling updates, can anyone advise us how to change the source code to achieve it

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion :)

Comment: I added a 'danger' section above with more details.

Comment: Great that worked for me, in my case the file was in: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/models/ability.rb, need to restart gitlab to apply the changes, thanks mate